# Trying to maintain spatial reference on newly created numpy array

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, numpy

I am trying to copy the values from raster into newly created array and then trying to save the array with same spatial reference as raster file

```
inRas = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

double_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
num_layer = int(double_layer)

output_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# information on input raster
dsc = arcpy.Describe(inRas)
sr = dsc.SpatialReference
ext = dsc.Extent
ll = arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMin)

arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRas, nodata_to_value=0)

shape = arr.shape
arcpy.AddMessage("image array created")

freq = numpy.empty(shape=(1, shape[1], shape[2]))
freq_numpy = numpy.uint8(freq)
arcpy.AddMessage("frequency array created")
#count = 1


# check for the 46 layers
# count is giving me total number of pixels

for x in range(0, shape[1]):
    for y in range(0, shape[2]):
        freq = 0
        for z in range(0, num_layer):
            # z is number of layer
            if arr[z][x][y] == 1:
                freq = freq + 1
            freq_numpy[0][x][y] = freq

arcpy.AddMessage("code finish file stored at"+ output_path)

newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(freq_numpy,ll,inRas.meanCellWdith,inRas.meanCellHeight)
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(newRaster, sr)

newRaster.save(output_path)
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonScripts\FrequencyBackup.py", line 66, in <module>
    cellHeight = inRas.meanCellHeight
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'meanCellHeight'

Failed to execute (Frequency).
Failed at Thu Dec 17 16:20:53 2015 (Elapsed Time: 4.75 seconds)
```

When I try to access `inRas.meanCellHeight` in Python console of ArcGIS, it returns a value. How can I access it from within my script?

Answer (score 1):

Your inRas can be path of raster or a RasterDataset object. In this error, I can see inRas is an Str Object. Your can't call `meanCellWdith` and `meanCellHeight` in this type of object

But using `dsc.meanCellHeight` and `dsc.meanCellHeight`, you can do wath you want

You don't use the good object...

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create a **raster object**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) in order to access properties. Right now, your variable `inRas` is just a string pointing to the raster on disk, and ArcPy doesn't recognize it as a "raster".

```
inRasName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inRas = Raster(inRasName)
```

Note: I think you'll still need to use the string when converting to a NumPy array...

```
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRasName, nodata_to_value=0)
```

Comment: I have typecasted the object into Raster and the ERROR has gone  I have checked all the parameters passing to the arcpy.NumpyArrayToRaster method still the resulted converted image is not spatially referenced

Comment: If you've got a separate question, [ask it as a separate question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Multiple questions are better than putting lots of problems into one :)